# Entity framework group locations by proximity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial-query

Given a table that contains rows with spatial data (a DbGeography column with coordinates) and a tolerance level (1000 miles, for instance), is it possible to fetch the rows from that table using EF, so that the rows are grouped based on proximity? In other words, if values of coordinate field on certain rows are closer than the given tolerance level, they are grouped? I looked around for available Spatial functions but didn't find one which would help with that. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to group by. Do you want to group into two groups, where distance `<` 1000 miles and `>=` 1000 miles? Have you tried using the [`DbGeography.Distance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance(v=vs.110).aspx) method as part of a query?

Comment: Not exactly. For instance, I have 5 points. Two of them are located closer than 1000 miles to each other. Other 3 point are 5000 miles away from these 2, but in relation to each other these 3 points are closer that 1000 miles. So as the output, I want to see 2 groups - one group of 2 points and one group of 3 points.

Comment: OK, so you want to group them by whether or not they are closer than 1000 miles to any other point - is that right?

Comment: Right. So the problem is that I have a lot of points scattered all over the map, and they have to be grouped in clusters based on proximity. And what I'm trying to do is to get these points grouped on the database level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give you two groups keyed on a boolean indicating whether or not points are closer to another by 1000 miles.

```
var threshold = 1609344.0;

var groups = from p1 in dbContext.Points
    let isCloseToOtherPoint = dbContext.Points.Any(p2 => p1.Geography.Distance(p2.Geography) < threshold)
    group p1 by isCloseToOtherPoint into g
    select g
```